# Copy data from one SQL Server database table to the other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to copy the data from one table to another between different servers.

If it is with in the same server and different databases, i have used the following

```
SELECT * INTO DB1..TBL1 FROM DB2..TBL1 (to copy with table structure and data)

INSERT INTO DB1..TBL1(F1, F2) SELECT F1, F2 FROM DB2..TBL1 (copy only data)
```

Now my question is copy the data from SERVER1 --> DB1--> TBL1 to SERVER2 --> DB2 -->TBL2

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the two servers are set up as Linked Servers in SQL Server then you can use the fully qualified name.

```
Insert Into Server1.Database1.dbo.Table1 (Col1, Col2)
Select Col1, Col2 From Server2.Database2.dbo.Table2
```

You can also right click a database and go to `Tasks` -> `Import Data` or `Export Data` (In SQL 2000 the menu option is called `All Tasks`)

This will launch wizard and perform the import/export for you.

EDIT:

Here is a link for creating linked servers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

You can see a list of servers by executing

```
select * from sys.servers
```

Or via the `Server Objects` > `Linked Servers` folders

HTH

Comment: Thanku for the quick reponse. How to check whether both the servers are set up as linked server or not? Can i set the other server so?
As this need to be done thru a stored procedure on a regular basis i can't use the option of wizard.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some additional information, thanks Barry

Comment: For those reading this later, I found out the hard way that, at least currently (SQL 2008 R2), you cannot enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` on a table through a linked server.

Comment: @JonSeigel: I think you have to create a dynamic SQL statement and execute it on the linked server using the `sp_executeSQL` stored procedure.

Comment: I read of a technique that runs the desired query as a parameter to a pass-through stored procedure... but that doesn't work. The problem is that when SQL goes to do a remote query, it creates a new connection, but doesn't pass through any connection options. Since `IDENTITY_INSERT` is per-connection, it doesn't get propagated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess . I am a little too late on this question :-), but you can try using SSIS in case 
the two servers are not set up as Linked Servers

Answer (score 0):

You can set up linked servers in SSMS and execute cross server queries.